# how to print some in like print in django on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a laravel project  running inside a VM. how can I print something like console.log("MSG"). i can see "laravel.log" file but cant print anything inside is.

Comment: ah no. as the project runs inside a VM. i don't have a console to print out. i am expecting to write out to something like a file  like laravel.log

Comment: Documentation should answer all your questions: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging

Comment: use Log;                Log::debug('hello world');   should log directly to storage/log/laravel.log